# How to solve Java IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

I am creating a method `public boolean add (int index, E elem)`, that adds an element at the index location in my linked list, but every time I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I am not able to figure it out why, searched on similar solutions but all in vain. This my code:

```
public boolean add(int index, E elem) {
    Node<E> node;
    node = new Node<>(elem);
    Boolean result = false;

    if (index > size) {
        System.out.println("Index out of bounds");
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        head = node;
        node.next = indices.get(index + 1);
        node.prev = null;
        node.next.prev = node;
        result = true;
    } else if (index == (size - 1)) {
        Node<E> node1 = indices.get(index - 1);
        tail = node;
        node1.next = node;
        node.next = null;
        node.prev = node1;
        result = true;
    } else if (index > 0 && index < (size - 1)) {
        Node<E> node1;
        Node<E> node2;
        node1 = indices.get(index - 1);
        node2 = indices.get(index);

        node.next = node1;
        node.prev = node2;

        node1.next = node;
        node2.prev = node;

        result = true;

    }

    indices.add(index, node);
    size++;
    System.out.println("Element " + elem + " added at the index: " + index);
    System.out.println("The size of the list now is: " + size);
    return result;
}
```

This are the class fields
`public class IDLList  {

```
private class Node<E>{

    E Data;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(E elem){

        this.Data = elem;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }

    Node (E elem, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next){

     this.Data = elem;
     this.prev = prev;
     this.next = next;

    }
}

    Node<E> head;
    Node<E> tail;
    int size;
    ArrayList<Node<E>> indices;`
```

This is the get function:
`public E get(int index){

```
    Node<E> node;
    node = indices.get(index);
    E value;
    value = node.Data;

    System.out.println("Value at index " + index + " is " + value);
    return value;
}`
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace from this exception.

Comment: If the index is too large, you print an error message, but you still continue executing the method. That should throw an exception instead, to signal the caller that he made a mistake, and stop the method execution.

Comment: `a.add(1,5); a.add(2,10); a.add(3,15); ` - after this we return the size of the list `a.add(5,6);` after executing `add` again `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

Comment: @VSoni, can you post your class fields too? It's hard to predict what's in your class.

Comment: @VSoni, read my comments in answer, seems there is a wrong logic of addition.

Comment: @Шах, I am going through your comments and trying to eliminate the errors. Thank you.

Comment: @VSoni, you're welcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your condition, it must be `index >= size` because indices begin from zero.

```
public boolean add (int index, E elem) {
    Node<E> node = new Node<>(elem); // You don't need to split definition and initialization

    if(index >= size) {
        System.out.println("Index out of bounds");

        return false;
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        head = node;
        node.next = indices.get(1); // Why is the next the second item, not the first? Maybe `indices.get(0)`?
        node.prev = null;
        node.next.prev = node;
    } else if (index == (size - 1)) {
        Node<E> node1 = indices.get(index - 1);
        tail = node;
        node1.next = node;
        node.next = null;
        node.prev = node1;
    } else if (index > 0 && index < (size - 1)) {
        Node<E> node1 = indices.get(index - 1);
        Node<E> node2 = indices.get(index);
        node.next = node1; // Why is `node1`, not `node2`?
        node.prev = node2; // Vice versa

        node1.next = node;
        node2.prev = node;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // If result is `false` why do u to add your node?
    indices.add(index, node);
    ++size;
    System.out.println("Element " + elem + " added at the index: " + index);
    System.out.println("The size of the list now is: " + size);

    return true;
}
```